# Populate multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel, serialization

I would like to do the follow:

a. Cell A2 is a dropdown list of products: Cellphone, Notebook, Television

b. Cell B2 is a dropdown list of quantity: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

c. C2 to C6 will display data based on A2 and B2.

Example:

```
if A2="Cellphone" and B2=2; C2="Cellphone Serial Number", C3="Cellphone Serial Number"

If A2="Notebook" and B2=5; C2="Notebook Serial Number", C3="Notebook Serial Number", C4="Notebook Serial Number", C5="Notebook Serial Number", C6="Notebook Serial Number"
```

How do I do the above in excel or VBA?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Darren, based on what you have asked I think you'll want to look into data validation(http://www.excel-easy.com/basics/data-validation.html) for a & b and the IF function for part c (https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function). I think those two will be the best place to start

Comment: Is notebook serial number something that is unique? Or in the 2nd example (notebook) would all 5 cells between C2 and C6 populate with the same number?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the vba translation for your pseudo-code above

```
Sub test()

If Range("A2") = "Cellphone" And Range("B2") = 2 Then
    'no need to reference each cell individually
    Range("C2:C3") = "Cellphone Serial Number"
ElseIf Range("A2") = "Notebook" And Range("B2") = 5 Then
    Range("C3:C6") = "Notebook Serial Number"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should include explanation for your code. In general, describing how and why certain commands or code solves a problem is more useful as it helps the OP and others to solve similar issues.